# Angular 7 - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

When I set the animations inside my component.ts I do not get any errors. But when exporting animations to a separate file I get the error shown below.

animations.ts

```
import { trigger, state, transition, style, animation, animate } from '@angular/animations';

export const transAnimation = animation([
  trigger('fade', [
    state('void', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    transition(':enter', [
      animate(300)
    ])
  ]),
  trigger('fadeOut', [
    state('void', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate(300)
    ])
  ]),
  trigger('shake', [
    state('false', style({ transform: 'translateX(10px)' })),
    transition('0 => 1', [
      animate(300)
    ])
  ]),
  trigger('slideIn', [
    state('void', style({ transform: 'translateX(10px)' })),
    transition(':enter', [
      animate(300)
    ])
  ]),
  trigger('hideShow', [
    state('false', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    transition('0 => 1', animate(300)),
  ])
]);
```

component.ts

```
import { transAnimation } from '../../animations';
[enter image description here][1]
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-update',
  templateUrl: './card-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-update.component.scss'],
  animations: [transAnimation]
})
```

Comment: try to export it like this `export const transAnimation = ()=> animation([...`

Comment: @EugenSunic Error: Unable to resolve animation metadata node #undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was exporting an array. When exporting each trigger separately it works!